# Whats wrong with my SQLITE3 insert method?

Tags: objective-c

Very confused by this... my "DiscoveredCars" table begins with two records in it.   The first time I call this method with it inserts properly and the last line displays "3" for the number of records.

Yet the second time I call it, the SQL looks perfect yet for some reason it still is showing  "3" for the size and does not seem to be inserting properly?   Any ideas?

```
- (void)writeToDiscoveredCars: (Car *)car {

NSString *tempSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO DiscoveredCars (car_ID) VALUES (%i)", car.ID];

NSLog(@"size of discoveredis %i", [self numberRecordsForTable:@"DiscoveredRecipes"]);
NSLog(@"SQL insert is %@", tempSQL);

const char *sql = [tempSQL UTF8String];   
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

if (sqlResult == SQLITE_OK) {

    sqlResult = sqlite3_step(statement);

    if(sqlResult == SQLITE_DONE)
    {

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"1. problem with database");
    NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(myDatabase));
}

NSLog(@"size of discoveredis %i", [self numberRecordsForTable:@"DiscoveredCars"]);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never execute your query by calling `sqlite3_step`.

```
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

if (sqlResult == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlResult = sqlite3_step(statement); //Execute!
    //check the result for completion
    if(sqlResult == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: Whoops! You're correct... I had that in there and then I edited it out by accident when trying to troubleshoot.  I've updated the code in my post.  However, I'm still having the problem I described.   I know check the size of DiscoveredCars at beginning and end of method.   At the beginning it says 2, and end it says 3.   Then when I call a second time it says 2 and 3 again??  Is the database getting recreated each time or something?

Comment: Whoops again... I found the place where I was re-initializing it.  Thanks Joe